# PHP: error on installing curl by homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I tried to install curl by following command:

```
  brew install php5-curl
```

but it gives this error:

```
  Warning: No avaliable formula with the name "php-curl".
  ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
  Error: No similarly named formulae found.
  ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
  Error: No previously deleted formula found.
  ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
  Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

am using mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you just want to install cURL, then you should rather use:

  ```
   brew install curl
  ```
- If you want to download php with cURL, then you can use the following steps:

`cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core`
`curl -s    https://github.com/dossy/homebrew-core/commit/b75fe286f79e2b89548c5ed1bbe1958313c5c103.patch    | patch -p1`
`brew reinstall php --build-from-source`

Comment: Thanks, i installed lot of services by this but the above error is showing in some of these services: xdebug, xsl, fpmn, apcu, imap